# Win11 21H2->22H2 - Areca RAID card stops working

Tags: hardware-raid, resources, windows-11-v22h2, irq, windows-10-v21h2

I am currently running Windows 11 21H2 and everything works the way I want it. However, when I try to upgrade to version 22H2, the upgrade itself works fine, but after that, my Areca RAID card (ARC-1210), which is used to host the data drives, stops working - and naturally, all the disks connected to it disappear from the system. From what I can tell about the system, the problem is that for some reason, in 22H2 the system assigns the card's IRQ to a different device which causes the card driver to fail. I need to find some solution for this. I don't want to replace the card unless there is absolutely no other option.

In version 21H2, Device Manager says the card is working correctly on PCI Bus 4, device 14, function 0. The driver is the latest available (6.20.0.39) with Win11 support. The card is using two memory ranges (00000000FCD10000-00000000FCD10FFF and 00000000E0400000-00000000E07FFFFF) and IRQ 0xFFFFFFEC (-20).

After upgrading to 22H2, Device Manager says the card couldn't find the necessary resources (Code 12). The driver is the same. The resources aren't displayed in the main UI, but if I switch to a view by resources, I can see that the memory ranges are fine, but the IRQ is not - instead of the Areca card, it got assigned to the USB 3 eXtensible Host Controller as one of many (10+) IRQs. If I disable the controller and reboot, the IRQ gets assigned to the network card (again, one of many IRQs).

There doesn't seem to be a difference whether I initiate the upgrade from the Windows Update or from the Upgrade Assistant or from the ISO image.

I wanted to set the IRQs manually ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-disable-pci-bus-irq-steering-in-windows-695c360f-1aae-471e-878e-07ff971b8e02 ), but I don't have a "PCI bus" device and none that seemed at least remotely relevant contained the checkbox described.

My motherboard's UEFI setup doesn't seem to contain any settings that would allow me to manually assign IRQs. In any case, since Win11 21H2 is working fine, I don't think it's a motherboard issue.

Any idea of what might help? Thank you.

**Note: This is not a question of "How to get my data back". That is taken care of. I am trying to solve the problem of "How to upgrade to 22H2 while keeping my RAID functioning".**

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to quickly rollback to 21H2 and test that your data
is all there. If this passes well, ensure that you have good backups.

For the moment you may block updates and
[Specify Target Feature Update Version in Windows 11](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/specify-target-feature-update-version-in-windows-11.3811/)
as 21H2.

You might have better luck with the next release of Windows 11
or with the same update some time in the future when it will be
fixed.

One more option is to signal the problem to Microsoft in
the Feedback Hub. If they answer, they might know of a fix.

(As an anecdote, I also once had a Windows Update that was
destructive for a device. I blocked updates and tried again
every couple of months.
After 6 months, with no reason at all and for the same major
Windows version, suddenly everything worked.)

Comment: The data is not a problem. Downgrade to my backups of the OS works perfectly, so I can always return. I am very careful about that. My problem is that I am stuck at 21H2, and while that is not an issue now, it will be an issue in three months when it stops being supported.

Comment: Try to go to 22H1 which is still supported, following my answer.

Comment: I don't think there is a 22H1 version in existence.

Comment: Apparently, 21H2 will be supported a bit longer, I was mistakenly looking at Windows 10. But still, I need to find a solution before November 2023 :-(

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my answer. One more option is to signal the problem to Microsoft in the Feedback Hub. If they answer, they might know of a fix.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the hyper-v & sandbox drivers used in 22H2.
Uninstall them from the optional feature list and Areca will work again.

I have the same issue, but luckily i found the reason that was causing this problem just a few days after 22H2 came out.
On the other hand, i can't use sandbox, but i prefer to have my raid card working

Comment: Very interesting. I'll need to give this a try over the weekend, but it does sound like we might have a solution!

Comment: I am pretty sure this really is the problem. Unfortunately, it's not enough to just remove the optional features - Hyper-V is deeply integrated into Windows and I would have to remove much more to get rid of it completely, which is probably what I would need in order to get the controller back to work. It would probably be much easier if I started off with a clean install without Hyper-V.

Comment: In the apps > optional features , click on "more windows features".

Check the list with the available features and make sure that the following is uninstalled :

1) "hyper-v" box is unticked.
2) "virtual machine platform" box is unticked.
3) "windows sandbox" box is unticked.
4) "windows sybsystem for linux" box is unticked.
5) "windows hypervisor platform" box is unticked.

I am not sure if all these must be uninstalled, but you can try some combinations after success .... Here is an image with the feature list : https://pasteboard.co/Fu1TTPXji47s.jpg